# Autoloading a custom package in Laravel7

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload

Sorry if my question looks so basic...

Am trying to use the following package in a fresh Laravel7 installation.

https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify

As like they mentioned i used 'composer require phpclassic/php-shopify' command to install this package. It is done successfully and i see it under 'Vendor/phpclassic/php-shopify/' folder. Now i want to use it in my controller...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PHPShopify\ShopifySDK;

class ShopifyConnectionController extends Controller
{
    function index(Request $request){

        $config = array(
            'ShopUrl' => config('app.shopify_app_url'),
            'ApiKey' => config('app.shopify_app_api_key'),
            'SharedSecret' => config('app.shopify_app_api_secret'),
        );

        PHPShopify\ShopifySDK::config($config);
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
?>
```

Am getting following error...

```
Error
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PHPShopify\ShopifySDK' not found
```

Now i see that the package is not auto loaded. I tried using "composer dump-autoload" command and tried adding the folder path in autoload section of composer.json file, etc... am keep getting the same error... I also noticed the "composer dump-autoload" command showing...

```
Discovered Package: facade/ignition 
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
etc...
```

but not the package i installed. Those discovered packages also in the same vendor folder. Then why is my package is not being discovered by Composer autoload when i run that command ? Someone kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are simply missing a backslash. This tells the autoloader that the file you are looking for is not in the namespace your controller resides in.

```
\PHPShopify\ShopifySDK::config($config);
```

And since you've already imported `ShopifySDK` there's no need for a FQCN. Just use the class:

```
ShopifySDK::config($config);
```

Comment: So I actually forgot to metion that the package is not being discovered by Laravel because it's missing some key components of a Laravel package, a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#service-providers) and the [`extra.laravel` option](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#package-discovery) containing the service provider's FQCN in the `composer.json`.

Comment: ok. thanks for the info. Yes it is not a package developed dedicated for Laravel framework.